# image_container remains null therefore it throws the error?

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I am trying to fetch the images from google using html dom but it throws this errorFatal error: **Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\nq\qimages.php on line 33**
I am not able to make out why image_container remains null. please see the below code and point out where i am going wrong.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Images</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="qimages.php" method="Post">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Text:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="image" id="ImageType" value=""></td>
<td><input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Click to Submit"></td>

</tr>
</table>
</form>
<br>

</body>
</html> 

<?php
include "simple_html_dom.php";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
    $search_query = $_POST['image'];


    // $search_query = "love";
    $search_query = urlencode( $search_query );
    $html = file_get_html( "https://www.google.com/search?q=$search_query&tbm=isch" );
    $image_container = $html->find('div#rcnt', 0);
    $images = $image_container->find('img');
    $image_count = 30; //Enter the amount of images to be shown
    $i = 0;
    foreach($images as $image){
        if($i == $image_count) break;
        $i++;

        // DO with the image whatever you want here (the image element is  '$image'):
        echo $image;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Try it like this: `$html->find('#rcnt', 0)`

Comment: I already tried but still same error.please check for something else...

Comment: `$html` is an object? can you `var_dump` it?

Comment: I didn't get you?when we echo $html we get the result in the form of whole html page..We want only image not whole page so I tried the following code.

Comment: yes $html is an object....it is not null. and also it gives result on echo.

Comment: $image_container gives null on var_dump...what to do for that.?

Comment: Try the second answer from the question above

Comment: @ Matei which question dude?

Comment: Your question has been marked as duplicate.. Read the answer of the question which has been asked before